# How to determine if the difference between two of the "same" datasets is significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

I have two distinct datasets that represent the price of the same product being advertised via two different channels. What I'm trying to determine is if the difference of the sold price on each platform is significant. The datasets would look like this:

```
Channel1Price   Channel2Price   PriceDifference
        10000          9500            -500
        4000           5000             1000
        5000           5000              0
        8000           7500            -750
```

I've looked at the different variants of a t-test and f-test. I don't even know if those are the right thing to use for this though. What I want to know is if over the entire dataset the difference between Channel1Price and Channel2Price is significant. The concept I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is that how the difference for each "row" rolls up to reflect the overall dataset.

Comment: What does each row represent? Is there a natural pairing between 10000 and 9500, or could the Channel2Price column go 5000, 7000, 9500, 7000 (no change to the Channel1Price column) without changing anything?

Comment: Each row represents a distinct product sold for a different day or set of days. You can imagine each row like an airline ticket for a day. Channel1 is Expedia, Channel2 is Kayak. Does that help?

Comment: A different product (e.g. car vs kumquat) or a different instance of the same product (e.g. two kumquats)?

Comment: I think neither actually. The same instance of the same product, just sold on two different platforms.

Comment: So a kumquat goes for 10000 on one channel, and the literal exact same piece of fruit goes for 9500 on a different channel?

Comment: While that sounds non-sensical, yes.

Comment: Look into paired t-testing and see if that does about what you want. Report back whether or not it does.

Comment: @Dave: a paired t test seems to be exactly what the OP is asking about. Do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: Does the same product appear in more than one row? This could be a repeated measures  problem.

Comment: @Michelle if I'm understanding your question correctly, I don't think so. To use the airline ticket example from above, the same seat for the same flight can't be sold twice.

Comment: Do the differences (PriceDifference column) follow a normal distribution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case for the paired t-test. Or, if the price distributions are too far from a normal distribution, use bootstrap or a permutation test.

This as a starting point. There is not very much information in the Q, so conceivably there might be complications we are not told.